# Trouble with import statements in Typescript and Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, typeorm

So, I'm trying to start a new project but I keep running into the following error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wl7fa.png)

(Because somehow I can't embed images yet)
The error: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Common solutions I've found, like editing the tsconfig.json or adding "type":"modules" to the package.json have done nothing to help me out.

Here goes my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ihanduapp_v2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "dev": "nodemon dist/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/node": "^16.10.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.13",
    "ts-node": "^10.2.1",
    "typescript": "^4.4.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "class-validator": "^0.13.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "pg": "^8.7.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.37"
  }
}
```

... and my tsconfig.json file as well:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2019",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2019"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@src/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@test/*": ["./test/*"]
    },
    "rootDirs": ["./src", "./test"],
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*.ts", "./test/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["./node_modules/*", "dist"]
}
```

I have no idea what to do, especially because I can't seem to find how to make TypeORM work with the "require" syntax, as a way to just go around the problem... Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1:

The file which is causing me problems is located at: src/models/User.ts and is as follows:

```
import {
  Column,
  CreateDateColumn,
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from "typeorm";
import { MaxLength, MinLength } from "class-validator";

@Entity()
export default class Patient {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  id!: string;

  @MaxLength(100)
  @MinLength(1, { message: "The name cannot be empty" })
  @Column({
    length: 100,
    unique: true,
  })
  patientName!: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt!: Date;
}
```

Edit 2:
I'm running the code by using the two scripts I've created

yarn watch (tsc -w)

followed by

yarn dev (nodemon dist/index.js)

Edit 3:

Here is the output of running tsc for that file in particular

```
"use strict";
var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
    var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
    else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
    return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
};
var __metadata = (this && this.__metadata) || function (k, v) {
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.metadata === "function") return Reflect.metadata(k, v);
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const typeorm_1 = require("typeorm");
const class_validator_1 = require("class-validator");
let Patient = class Patient {
};
__decorate([
    (0, typeorm_1.PrimaryGeneratedColumn)("uuid"),
    __metadata("design:type", String)
], Patient.prototype, "id", void 0);
__decorate([
    (0, class_validator_1.MaxLength)(100),
    (0, class_validator_1.MinLength)(1, { message: "The name cannot be empty" }),
    (0, typeorm_1.Column)({
        length: 100,
        unique: true,
    }),
    __metadata("design:type", String)
], Patient.prototype, "patientName", void 0);
__decorate([
    (0, typeorm_1.CreateDateColumn)(),
    __metadata("design:type", Date)
], Patient.prototype, "createdAt", void 0);
Patient = __decorate([
    (0, typeorm_1.Entity)()
], Patient);
exports.default = Patient;
//# sourceMappingURL=Patient.js.map
```

Comment: please share how you are doing this

Comment: what information do you need, @DanielA.White?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: that's the thing, the codebase is already almost non existant. Apart from the .ts file which is causing me problems (which I already added), the only thing the program is doing is creating a server at port 3000, literally nothing else. I've also added the commands I'm using to run the program.

Comment: Why is your tsc outputting `import` statements, when you have `"module": "commonjs"`? Something seems odd, how are you running this?

Comment: I've just added that part as Edit 2. But it's just yarn watch (tsc -w) followed by yarn dev (nodemon dist/index.js)

Comment: What i mean is the error looks like it's from node's cjs loader, but with that config, the resulting js file shouldn't have any `import` statements left.

Comment: And I don't think it does. The error is signaled at /Users/eduardocampos/Desktop/INESC TEC/iHandUApp_v2/src/classes/Patient.ts:1 which is the original file. I've also added the outputted file as a clarification to the original question body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was actually on my `ormconfig.json`.

The `entities` and `migrations` options were pointing to the original `.ts` files in `src/` , when (obviously, in retrospect), they should be pointing to the `dist/` `.js` files.

Well, those were some interesting hours on my life down the drain...